# Only Exposing CiviCRM Contact from Active Group in Drupal Views?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

We have a directory (along with a Leaflet map) of our affiliates. Currently, the view is filtering the map and accompanying table of contacts based on the group ID (e.g. 200 = current affiliates).

What I've noticed is that when we remove an affiliate from said group, rather than delete them, the contact record still shows up in the Drupal view. I've added the "CiviCRM Groups: Is Active" filter, however that doesn't seem to be working.

Right now, these are my filters and this is the new filter setup I provided to the view:

CiviCRM Address: State/Province (exposed)  AND
CiviCRM Address: City / Suburb (exposed)  AND
CiviCRM Contacts: Display Name (exposed)

AND

CiviCRM Groups: Group ID (= 200)  AND
CiviCRM Groups: Is Active (True)

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you remove someone from a group, the status of their group membership is changed from 'Added' to 'Removed', so try adding another filter on status:

`CiviCRM Groups: Contact Status (= Added)`